# Fabric.js Undo Redo Functionality causing 2 steps at a time

Tags: fabricjs, undo-redo

I'm having a little trouble getting Undo/Redo to work when I'm using multiple ways to add objects. My editor has a button to add images, background, and text.

Therefore, I believe (please correct me if I'm wrong) I need to call the updateModifications() function each time I call a function that adds an image, background or text, along with each time the canvas is modified. I'm fairly certain the issue is that updateModifications is called too many times throughout the document.

```
function remove(){
  console.log(canvas.getActiveObject());
  var activeObjects = canvas.getActiveObjects();
      canvas.discardActiveObject()
      if (activeObjects.length) {
        canvas.remove.apply(canvas, activeObjects);
      }
      updateModifications(true);
}
canvas.on({
  'object:modified': function () {
    updateModifications(true);
  },
  'object:added': function() {
    updateModifications(true);
  }

});
function addText() {
  prodName = localStorage.getItem('storedName');
  var textObj = new fabric.IText(prodName, {
    fontSize: 22,
    top: 362.5,
    left: 262.5,
    hasControls: true,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontFamily: '"Montserrat",sans-serif',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    centeredrotation: true,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
  canvas.insertAt(textObj,0).setActiveObject(textObj);
  textToFront();
  canvas.renderAll();
  updateModifications(true);
}
```

This is creating some issues when code [based on zaid's SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069122/how-to-do-undo-redo-in-fabric-js-using-enlivenobjects);

```
var mods = 0;
var state = [];
function updateModifications(savehistory) {
  if (savehistory === true) {
      myjson = JSON.stringify(canvas);
      state.push(myjson);
  }
}

undo = function undo() {
  if (mods < state.length) {
      canvas.clear().renderAll();
      canvas.loadFromJSON(state[state.length - 1 - mods - 1]);
      canvas.renderAll();
      mods += 1;
  }
}

redo = function redo() {
  if (mods > 0) {
      canvas.clear().renderAll();
      canvas.loadFromJSON(state[state.length - 1 - mods + 1]);
      canvas.renderAll();
      mods -= 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call addText(), you are calling updateModifications() and then have an event listener 'object:added' also calling updateModifications(). Either remove the event listener or simply dont call updateModifications() in addText().

Not sure then mate but this works for me in fabric 2.5:

```
var CanvasState = [];
var CanvasStateIndex = -1;
saveCanvas()

function refreshCanvas(){
  canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
}

function saveCanvas(){
  var newState = canvas.toJSON();
  CanvasState.push(newState);
  CanvasStateIndex = CanvasStateIndex +1;
  while (CanvasStateIndex < (CanvasState.length)-1){
    CanvasState.pop();
  }
}

function undo(){
  if (CanvasStateIndex >= 0){
    CanvasStateIndex = CanvasStateIndex -1;
    var jsonCanvas = CanvasState[CanvasStateIndex];
    canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonCanvas, refreshCanvas, function(o, obj){ 
    })
  } else{
    console.log('undo error CanvasStateIndex = '+CanvasStateIndex)
  }
}

function redo(){
  if (CanvasStateIndex < CanvasState.length -1){
    CanvasStateIndex = CanvasStateIndex +1;
    var jsonCanvas = CanvasState[CanvasStateIndex];
    canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonCanvas, refreshCanvas, function(o, obj){
    })
  }else{
    console.log('redo error CanvasStateIndex = '+CanvasStateIndex)
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried removing it from everywhere except object added and object modified, but it still weirdly seems to go back 2 times.

Comment: Ok, not sure whats wrong but edited my answer to offer an alternative that works for me

Comment: Thanks for updated script, undo currently goes back 1 step, and redo throws: redo error CanvasStateIndex = 2. I've added saveCanvas into only object:added and object:modified

Comment: Hey, sorry had a deadline to meet! You should only see that error if you try to redo beyond the top of the 'stack'. Have you tried dropping the event listeners and calling saveCanvas() manually (ie as part of the function that add / modifies things)? If your functions are modifying an object twice, you will call saveCanvas() twice

Comment: That's definitely the issue. Thanks for your help! I've just got to work out the best way to prevent it from doubling up.